# Get Image on Product detail page

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I am creating system.xml file for the custom image upload and i want to display uploaded images on product detail pages.
can any one help me?
i am using magento-1.9.2.3 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for showing product image gallery..

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<?php if($_images){?>            
    <?php $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++; ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(108,90); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?php $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /><?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```